# CSS2 clipping fixed width auto height possible?

Tags: css

Im using this css property to clip the content inside a div:

```
div {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(0px,200px,100px,0px);
   overflow: none;
   width: 200px;
}
```

At the momment you see the height and width of the clipping area is fixed to 100x200. I want to mantein the fixed width but I need the height to be auto, I mean, relative to the div content. Is this possible? I tried:

```
rect(0px,200px,auto,0px)
rect(0px,200px,100%,0px)
```

But they seam to not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: is your clip approach necessary? (in other words do you mask anything??). With clipping, I don't think there is any solution to your problem

Comment: I dont know, this is the script http://jsfiddle.net/97pcj/1/ what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `none` a valid value of `overflow`? Should it not be `hidden`?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp